# Equidistant points on a circle with skips

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles

I have $n$ distinct points $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ on a circle, with the property that the angle $\theta_{i,(i+1)\%n}$ between consecutive points is the same for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
(This angle is measured counterclockwise from $x_i$ to $x_{(i+1)\%n}$.)
This does not necessarily imply that two consecutive points $x_i$ and $x_{(i+1)\%n}$ are also spatially consecutive on the circle.
For example, we could have $x_0=(1,0)$, $x_1=(0,-1)$, $x_2=(-1,0)$ and $x_3=(0,1)$, with $\theta_{i,(i+1)\%n}=3\pi/2$.
Show that

$$
\min_{j\neq i} \theta_{ij} = \frac{2\pi}{n}\quad \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}.
$$

Alternatively, show with a counterexample that the statement above does not hold.

**Hints and progress so far**

Since the angles $\min_{j\neq i} \theta_{ij}$ must add up to the full circle, we know that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \min_{j\neq i} \theta_{ij} = 2\pi.
$$

Since the angles $\theta_{i,(i+1)\%N}$ must add up to an integer number of circulations, we know that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \theta_{i,(i+1)\%n} = 2k\pi \text{ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_{\phi(i)}$ be the next marked point on the circle clockwise (not necessarily $x_{i+1}$). We have

$$x_i, x_{\phi(i)}, \ldots, x_{i+1}, x_{\phi(i+1)}, x_{\phi(i)+1},$$

where some points may coincide, but necessarily $x_{\phi(i+1)}$ is before $x_{\phi(i)+1}$. But

$$|x_{i+1}-x_i| = |x_{\phi(i)+1}-x_{\phi(i)}|,$$

thus

$$|x_{\phi(i)+1}-x_{i+1}| = |x_{\phi(i)}-x_{i}|,$$

and

$$|x_{\phi(i+1)}-x_{i+1}| \leqslant |x_{\phi(i)}-x_{i}|.$$

Vice versa inequality is also true, thus $\min_{\theta_{ij}}=|x_{\phi(i)}-x_{i}|$ is constant.

Comment: Hm, ok, wait, why $x_{\phi(i+1)}$ needs to come before $x_{\phi(i)+1}$, starting from $x_i$ and going counterclockwise?

Comment: Because $x_{\phi(i+1)}$ is the next point after $x_{i+1}$ by definition (but $x_{\phi(i+1)}$ and $x_{\phi(i)+1}$may coincide).

Comment: I see it now. $x_{\phi(i)+1}$ cannot come before $x_{i+1}$, otherwise $\theta_{\phi(i),\phi(i+1)}$ would be smaller than $\theta_{i,i+1}$.

Comment: ... and, I guess that the "vice-versa" part follows from the circularity of the indexes, right?

Comment: Yes, or simpler: from the same argument for $i-1$ istead of $i$.

Comment: Deleted one old comment because it was made obsolete by the correction in the answer.